# Which Postgres multi client_encoding best practice?

Tags: postgresql, encoding

I have a DB server and client with encoding UTF8,and the client some time write data in SJIS or LATIN1,

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd5 0x78
```

I tried to set client_encoding to SJIS then it's worked

I wonder why this error happened?

Because I think UTF8 was support both of them descriped in this docs

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/multibyte.html#id-1.6.10.5.7

Are the any way to make it automatic convert without setting encoding manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to explicitly tell it what encoding the client uses.
Postgres does support automatic *conversion* between the encodings, but it does not support automatic encoding *detection*. If the client is assumed to use UTF-8 but then writes some SJIS bytes, they simply might end up as invalid.

Comment: Thanks for clean my mind about  `conversion` and `detection`. I got that